# To find area of the given figure

Tags: geometry

> [image: The Pic]
>
> In the figure above, $BC = 10 cm, EF = 8 cm, ID = 7 cm, AH = 6 cm, HF = 12 cm, BG = 8 cm$. Find the area of the figure (in ${cm}^2$).

Here, I was unable to work out the length $HG$ despite my best efforts.

But met an even disenchanting solution, which as follows:

> The figure is made up of trapeziums $ABCD$ and $ADEF$. 
> Area of the figure $ = [\frac 12 (BC+AD) \times BG] + [\frac 12 (AD+EF)FH]$ 
> $=[\frac 12(10+21)8]+[\frac 12(21+8)12]$
> $=298$ 
> Disenchanting because here $HG=0$.

But, is it even possible to find $HG$ or whether it can't be done without the assumption as made above? Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to find $GH$; it is irrelevant (it is not a constant value: read the last paragraph). I don’t think you can infer $HG=0$ from the given solution.

If $FH\perp AD, EI\perp AD$ and $FE\parallel AD$, then $FE=HI$ so that $HI=8$.

Thus $$AD=AH+HI+ID=6+8+7=21.$$ and the rest follows.

Actually, the line BC can be shifted around (vertical translation) so that G aligns exactly with H, or such that G and H are separated by some arbitrary length. This is because no restrictions have been imposed on trapezium ABCD except the lengths of its parallel sides.

Comment: Oh boy! Another one of my mis-reads. I mistook the given length AH as I read it as AG.
I talked of this issue [in this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4494572/how-to-avoid-mis-reading-and-why-its-happening). But would still love to know if your answer would have changed had it been AG instead of AH in the OP.

Comment: For the second part of the comment, yes it would. GH would then be needed as there’d be some overlap.

Comment: Alright, thank you